# XML Serialization Deserialization HTML Entities C# .net

Tags: c#, html, .net, xml, serialization

We have some XML files which we get as input (whose format is not under our control).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GroupFile..>
    <Group id="10" desc="Description">
        <Member id="117">&#x00B0;</Member>
    </Group>    
</GroupFile>
```

This file can contain HTML entity code representation of symbols like "°" (represented as "`&#x00B0;`" in hex). This file is deserialized to *Group* and *Member* class objects. When XML deserializing the *Member* element value is correctly read as "°" and displayed in a grid. When serializing back the earlier objects back into XML, the *Member* value is saved as "°" instead of "`&#x00B0;`".

Deserialization - Correct

`<Member id="117">&#x00B0;</Member>` deserializes into Member object with value °

Serialization - Issue here

The same Member object with value ° serializes into `<Member id="117">°</Member>`instead of `<Member id="117">&#x00B0;</Member>`

How can this be prevented and get it serialized back as "`&#x00B0;`" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must then apply a **custom serialization/deserializatio**n to do so.

Using `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode/HtmlDecode` is not sufficient since it provide the **decimal encoding**. I added the following (*could be improved in terms of error catching*) to keep the hex escaped characters in the xml serialization.

**Update:**
In order to avoid automatic escape of special character, you must write a custom Xml serializer for the class as seen below and use `WriteRaw`

If you use the XmlSerializer:

```
public class GroupFile
{
    [XmlElement("Group")]
    public Group[] Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Member")]
    public Member[] Members { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Member : IXmlSerializable
{

    public static string DecimalToHexadecimalEncoding(string html)
    {
        var splitted = html.Split('#');
        var res = Int32.Parse(splitted[1].Replace(";", string.Empty));
        return "&#x" + res.ToString("x4") + ";";
    }

    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }       

    [XmlIgnore]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string HexValue
    {
        get
        {
            // convert to hex representation
            var res = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Value);
            res = DecimalToHexadecimalEncoding(res);
            return res;
        }
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        var attributeValue = reader.GetAttribute("id");
        if (attributeValue != null)
        {
            Id = Int32.Parse(attributeValue);
        }
        // Here the value is directly converted to string "°"
        Value = reader.ReadElementString();            
        reader.ReadEndElement();           
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("id", Id.ToString());
        writer.WriteRaw(HexValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: &, <, > etc are special XML characters which are escaped during xml serialization. The question was about HTML entity symbols like ° deserializing properly from escape codes but serializing as such not as codes.

<Member id="117">&#x00B0;</Member>  deserializes properly and i get member value as °. But when serializing back I get <Member id="117">°</Member>  instead of <Member id="117">&#x00B0;</Member>

Comment: @Socrates I've updated the answer with your comment.

Comment: Member object with Value = "°". HexValue after calling DecimalToHexadecimalEncoding will be "&#x00b0;". And during serialization & will be escaped automatically by the serializer. So the end result will be <Member id="117">&amp;#x00b0</Member>  which makes the result invalid again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HSharp to deserialize HTML.
[HSharp](https://github.com/Anduin2017/HSharp) is a library used to analyse markup language like HTML easily and fastly.
Install:`Install-Package Obisoft.HSharp`

```
var NewDocument = HtmlConvert.DeserializeHtml($@"
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset={"\"utf-8\""}>
    <meta name={"\"viewport\""}>
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Some Text</h1>
<table>
    <tr>OneLine</tr>
    <tr>TwoLine</tr>
    <tr>ThreeLine</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>");

Console.WriteLine(NewDocument["html"]["head"]["meta",0].Properties["charset"]);
Console.WriteLine(NewDocument["html"]["head"]["meta",1].Properties["name"]);
foreach (var Line in NewDocument["html"]["body"]["table"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(Line.Son);
}
```

That will output:

```
utf-8
viewport
OneLine
TwoLine
ThreeLine
```

and you can also foreach the tag in html.